# How to download file from mongo and store in a folder

Tags: node.js, mongodb, gridfs

I have created an MEAN stack web application which uploads image file and store in mongo database. I used Mongo GridFs to store files in Mongo database. it is working fine. 
Now I have requirement to create a job using Nodejs to download those images in a folder. I am using "openDownloadStream" method of grid fs to get the file stream. How to store this stream as file in a folder.
There is no http call as this is a simple function which will run as a batch.

Comment: Use fs to create a file using stream

Comment: can you add more details of your code here?